# How to make a twoWay binding to a usercontrol property (Public String)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

Find all the results are about how to binding a control in a usercontrol.
But my problem now is much simple that just binding the value in a 
Pulic String MyBindingString { get; set; }

I tried as a , 
but got a error when enter that page
Set property 'xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xx.MyBindingString' threw an exception

Thanks for your help.

---

Now, I find that when I binding in the code like 
"Text={Binding MyCustomText, Mode=TwoWay}"

what actually passing to the MyBindingString is class: System.Windows.Data.Binding
not the value ...

Any idea?

Comment: You need to post some code if you want some help, at least post your XAML and the code for the class & proeprty (strip out the code from the class that isn't related to the property).

Comment: Is there anything in InnerException?

Answer (score 1):

If the title of your question is well-defined. you are looking for "Mode" in binding.

for two way, Mode=TwoWay,
example:

```
"Text={Binding MyCustomText, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create bindable properties in your UserControl- this is the way to do it:

```
        #region MyCustomText

        public string MyCustomText
        {
            get { return GetValue(MyCustomTextProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(MyCustomTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustomText",
          typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMyCustomTextChanged)));

        public static void OnMyCustomTextChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = sender as MyUserControl;
            var value = e.NewValue as string;
        }

        #endregion MyCustomText
```